# OpenGL - Use non normalized texcoords

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

By default, OpenGL uses normalized TexCoords, which mean the value must be between 0 and 1 ([0..1]). the common implementation of `Vertex` must be look something like this:

```
// Common Implementation of Vertex
Vertex v = new Vertex(
    // Position
    new Vector2(0f, 500f), 
    // 'Normalized' TexCoords [0..1]
    new Vector2(0f, 1f), 
    // Color of Vertex
    Color.White
);

// Or in immediate mode..
// It's the same, we still need to specify between 0 and 1 ([0..1])
GL.TexCoord2(1f, 0f);
```

However, is it possible to use non normalized texcoord (so it specified in pixel format, which mean the value must be between 0 and size ([0..size])) in OpenGL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still can't figure out why `GL.Ortho` (while in `MatrixMode.Texture`) isn't give me intended result..

So finally, I ended up with calculating matrix manually:

```
        // Initialize identity matrix
        Matrix4 matrix = new Matrix4
                         (1f, 0f, 0f, 0f,
                          0f, 1f, 0f, 0f,
                          0f, 0f, 1f, 0f,
                          0f, 0f, 0f, 1f);

        // Or use Matrix4.Identity (in OpenTK case), that should be equal(?)

        // Convert to normalized
        matrix[0, 0] = 1f / textureWidth;
        matrix[1, 1] = 1f / textureHeight;

        // Apply the matrix to texture matrix
        GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Texture);
        GL.LoadMatrix(ref matrix);
```

Comment: It's because `glOrtho()` builds a matrix that maps the specified range to [-1.0, 1.0], which is what you normally want to map coordinates to NDC. But in this case, you need texture coordinates in the range [0.0, 1.0].

Answer (score 1):

To set up the texture transformation for this case, use:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
glScalef(1.0f / textureWidth, 1.0f / textureHeight, 1.0f);
```

It looks like you made attempts to do the same thing with `glOrtho()`. While that's possible, the following will **not** give the desired result:

```
glOrtho(0.0, textureWidth, 0.0, textureHeight, ...);
```

`glOrtho()` builds a matrix that transforms the given ranges to the range [-1.0, 1.0] in both coordinate directions. This makes sense because it is mostly used for vertex coordinates that need to be transformed into NDC space, which is [-1.0, 1.0].

However, for texture coordinates, you want to transform the [0.0, textureWidth] and [0.0, textureHeight] ranges to the range [0.0, 1.0]. If you were completely set on using `glOrtho()`, the correct call would be:

```
glOrtho(-textureWidth, textureWidth, -textureHeight, textureHeight, 1.0, -1.0);
```

Since this now maps [-textureWidth, textureWidth] to [-1.0, 1.0], this means that it maps [0.0, textureWidth] to [0.0, 1.0], which is the desired transformation.

But it's much easier and cleaner to use the `glScalef()` call shown at the start of my answer.

Comment: Now everything make sense! (and seems the code a bit cleaner with this one), thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since glMatrixMode and glLoadMatrix are deprecated in modern OpenGL, it might be worth revisiting the fact that you can use GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE instead of GL_TEXTURE_2D. You can't use mipmaps, and you need to use sampler2DRect instead of sampler2D() or texture() within your shader, but you have direct, non-normalized texel lookup that way.

The feature is safe (core) all the way back to OpenGL 3.1, so it'll run on your 10-year-old Intel HD Graphics.